# Failed to get kotlin-dsl plugin 3.6

Tags: android, kotlin

Android Studio:  4.0.1
AGP:  4.0.1
GRADLE: 6.6.1

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':buildSrc'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':buildSrc:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.gradle.kotlin:plugins:1.3.6.
     Required by:
         project :buildSrc > org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl:org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl.gradle.plugin:1.3.6
      > Could not resolve org.gradle.kotlin:plugins:1.3.6.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/gradle/kotlin/plugins/1.3.6/plugins-1.3.6.module'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/org/gradle/kotlin/plugins/1.3.6/plugins-1.3.6.module?referrer'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Are you solve the question?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you solved it?